# Lagrange multipliers in optimal control - regularity of constraints?

Tags: optimization, calculus-of-variations, optimal-control

Assume we want to minimize the loss,
\begin{align}
J(u) &= \int_{0}^{T}l(x(t),u(t))dt \\
    \text{s.t.}\quad &\dot{x}(t) = f(x(t),u(t)), \quad x(0)=x_0.
\end{align}
For necessary conditions many textbooks (e.g. [Calculus of Variations and Optimal Control Theory - by Daniel Liberzon](https://www.jstor.org/stable/j.ctvcm4g0s)) then introduce the Lagrange multiplier $\lambda(t)$ and calculate the variation of,
\begin{equation}\mathcal{L}(u) = \int_{0}^{T}l(x(t),u(t))dt - \int_{0}^{T}\lambda(t)^\top\left[\dot{x}(t) - f(x(t),u(t))\right]dt.\star\label{lagrange}\end{equation}
I understand that we may view the differential equation as a constraint $g(u)=0$ with,
$$g:U\to Y, u\mapsto \dot{x}(\cdot,u)-f(x(\cdot,u),u(\cdot))$$
where U and Y are function spaces and $x(\cdot,u)$ indicates the implicit dependency on $u$. We may then use Lagrange multipliers as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multipliers_on_Banach_spaces#:%7E:text=The%20Lagrange%20multiplier%20theorem%20for%20Banach%20spaces,-Let%20X%20and&text=Let%20g%20%3A%20U%20%E2%86%92%20Y,constraint%20that%20g%20is%20zero.) to get to $\star$. What I am confused about is:

- Wouldn't we need that $u$ is regular point i.e. $Dg(u)$ is surjective to apply Lagrange multipliers? But $g$ is by construction a zero map and therefore this fails, doesn't it? And also introducing a constraint that is always satisfied sounds a bit silly.
- I have seen that we can check regularity when we view it as an optimization problem in $U\times X$ (where $x\in X$, see [Optimization by vector space methods](http://sites.science.oregonstate.edu/%7Eshow/old/142_Luenberger.pdf)) and in this case the constraints seems intuitively reasonable too. But is there a justification for Lagrange multipliers for the problem in $U$?